# Syncing files with Docker bind mount when VOLUME directive is present in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

Hi I'm having trouble syncing local project files with a Docker container. I'm using a Dockerfile that has VOLUME directive:

`VOLUME [ "/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles"`

When I'm running the container with docker compose with following service using bind mount:

```
 app:
   volumes:
     - type: bind
       source: .
       target: /usr/local/src/project-dir
```

Now when inside the container I use a command that generates some static assets to `/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles`, those files don't sync back to the local filesystem. Can You tell me why?

I expect the files generated in the container in `/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles`, to sync with local filesystem. However they do generate in the container but are nowhere to be seen in the host system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the VOLUME statement in the Dockerfile.

Your bind works correctly in that it maps your current host directory to `/usr/local/src/project-dir`.

But the VOLUME statement causes docker to create a docker volume and map that to `/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles`. Any files you create in `/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles` and below will be in the docker volume and not reflected in the bound directory.

To fix it, you can remove the VOLUME statement in the Dockerfile. Then all files you create in `/usr/local/src/project-dir` or below will be in the mapped directory on the host.

Comment: Yeah, when I remove it it works. I need it in the Dockerfile tho, because I need to expose those files, so that a proxy container can serve them to the browser. Is there a way to leave it as is but make it work. Maybe build targets?

Comment: It sounds like you want files in `/usr/local/src/project-dir/public/bundles` to both be in a volume and at the same time be in the host file system. There's no way to do that, I think.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought that maybe I can move the VOLUME declaration to the end of the Dockerfile and for local development target a stage that's before that, so that VOLUME is never build.

Comment: The Dockerfile `VOLUME` statement tells Docker to mount an anonymous volume on that directory if nothing else is mounted there.  Its most visible effect is prohibiting future `RUN` statements and `docker commit` from changing that directory; it is almost certainly safe to delete it.